# ¿Cómo crear un select multiple con wp_dropdown_categories en Wodpress?

Tags: wordpress

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a hacer que este wp_dropdown_categories sea de selección múltiple?

```
           $args=array(
                    'class'       => 'select-submit2',
                    'hide_empty'  => false,
                    'selected'    => $prop_category_selected,
                    'name'        => 'prop_category',
                    'id'          => 'prop_category_submit',
                    'orderby'     => 'NAME',
                    'order'       => 'ASC',
                    'show_option_none'   => esc_html__( 'None','properties'),
                    'taxonomy'    => 'property_category',
                    'hierarchical'=> true
                );
            wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

Comment: Revisa la primer respuesta de César, es correcta salvo por un parámetro faltante: `'echo' => 0,` a la función, en mi propia respuesta enlazo a la referencia en la documentación de WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

A priori tienes dos opciones:

1 - Modificar el dropdown antes de pintarlo.

```
$args=array(
    'class'       => 'select-submit2',
    'hide_empty'  => false,
    'selected'    => $prop_category_selected,
    'name'        => 'prop_category',
    'id'          => 'prop_category_submit',
    'orderby'     => 'NAME',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'show_option_none'   => esc_html__( 'None','properties'),
    'taxonomy'    => 'property_category',
    'hierarchical'=> true
);
$dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
$dropdown = str_replace('id=', 'multiple="multiple" id=', $dropdown);
```

2 - Utilizar wp_category_checklist()

Según la documentación:

```
wp_category_checklist( $post_id, $descendants_and_self, $selected_cats,
     $popular_cats, $walker, $checked_ontop);
```

Por lo tanto puedes definir un walker que en lugar de pintar los checkbox se encargue de pintar un select multiple. El walker por defecto es:

```
class Walker_Category_Checklist extends Walker {
    public $tree_type = 'category';
    public $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id'); //TODO: decouple this
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
    }
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }
    public function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) ) {
            $taxonomy = 'category';
        } else {
            $taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];
        }

        if ( $taxonomy == 'category' ) {
            $name = 'post_category';
        } else {
            $name = 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';
        }

        $args['popular_cats'] = empty( $args['popular_cats'] ) ? array() : $args['popular_cats'];
        $class = in_array( $category->term_id, $args['popular_cats'] ) ? ' class="popular-category"' : '';

        $args['selected_cats'] = empty( $args['selected_cats'] ) ? array() : $args['selected_cats'];

        if ( ! empty( $args['list_only'] ) ) {
            $aria_cheched = 'false';
            $inner_class = 'category';

            if ( in_array( $category->term_id, $args['selected_cats'] ) ) {
                $inner_class .= ' selected';
                $aria_cheched = 'true';
            }

            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/category-template.php */
            $output .= "\n" . '<li' . $class . '>' .
                '<div class="' . $inner_class . '" data-term-id=' . $category->term_id .
                ' tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-checked="' . $aria_cheched . '">' .
                esc_html( apply_filters( 'the_category', $category->name ) ) . '</div>';
        } else {
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/category-template.php */
            $output .= "\n<li id='{$taxonomy}-{$category->term_id}'$class>" .
                '<label class="selectit"><input value="' . $category->term_id . '" type="checkbox" name="'.$name.'[]" id="in-'.$taxonomy.'-' . $category->term_id . '"' .
                checked( in_array( $category->term_id, $args['selected_cats'] ), true, false ) .
                disabled( empty( $args['disabled'] ), false, false ) . ' /> ' .
                esc_html( apply_filters( 'the_category', $category->name ) ) . '</label>';
        }
    }
    public function end_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola César, tu primer respuesta es correcta, salvo que tienes que agregar `'echo' => 0,` al array de parámetros, [para que te devuelva la cadena HTML y no la imprima en pantalla](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/#return). Traté de editar la respuesta pero rechazaron mi edición: http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12434

Answer (score 0):

Además de los argumentos que ya estás pasando a la función, incluye un `'echo' => 0` [para que te devuelva el HTML](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/#return) y no lo imprima aún, y ahí puedes aplicar la sustitución que propone César González:

```
$multidropdown = str_replace('id=', 'multiple="multiple" id=', $dropdown);
```